# Restore default app icons from install disc?

Tags: applications, install, icon

I (Candybar) deleted some of my app icons and they are completely gone.
Is it possible to extract the icons for the system applications (e.g. Address Book, TextEdit) from the installation disc?

Alternative can anyone upload the icns files for the following applications:

```
Activity Monitor*
Address Book*
Adobe Bridge CS5
Adobe Dreamweaver CS5
Adobe Flash CS5
Adobe Photoshop CS5
Calculator*
Firefox
Google chrome
iTunes
Mail*
Photo Booth*
Safari
System Preferences*
TextEdit*
```

where asterisk is the system applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to open my install disc using [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) and extract the icons and put them in the app. I just searched for the app names such as "AddressBook".

Answer (score 1):

Candy Bar has a restore feature for icons to be returned to the system default.

Comment: I clicked restore, and it deleted all the icons instead of restoring them.

Comment: If rebooting and letting candy bar try again fails, it's likely the system is failing and not the app. You can reinstall the OS and preserve all your data - who knows what else is off if this is failing...